# Jquery html not working on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I do this  first

```
var columns = row.getElementsByTagName('td');

columns[2].innerHTML ='<Button class="btn btn-success" style="margin-right:4px;" onclick="savecategory(this.parentNode,this)">Save</Button>
```

now my function

```
function savecategory(but,save_button){
$(save_button).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span> Save');
$(save_button).attr("disabled",true);
//These two lines do not work

}
```

The lines inside savecategory does'nt work , but when i console it shows correct button

Edit here is complete function:

```
function savecategory(but,save_button){
  var row = but.parentNode;
var columns = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
var newmain = $(columns[0]).children('select[name=maincategory]').val();

columns[1].innerHTML = (columns[1].innerHTML).replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
var newcat = $(columns[1]).text();
var oldmain = columns[0].getAttribute('data-init');
var oldcat = columns[1].getAttribute('data-init');

$(save_button).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span> Save');
$(save_button).attr("disabled",true);

var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
    var arr= JSON.parse(this.responseText);
if(arr[0] == 1){
columns[0].innerHTML = newmain;
columns[1].innerHTML = newcat;
columns[1].setAttribute("contenteditable","false");
columns[0].setAttribute('data-init',newmain);
columns[1].getAttribute('data-init',newcat);

columns[2].innerHTML ='<Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editcategory(this.parentNode)"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit zmdi-hc-lg"></i></Button>';


$('select[name ="dishtype"] option[value="'+oldcat+'"]').remove();
$('select[name ="dishtype"]').append('<option value="' + newcat + '">' + newcat + '</option>');
var $alen = $('.scrollmenu').eq(0).children().length;


$('.scrollmenu').eq(0).find('a').each(function(){
  if($(this).attr('data-init').localeCompare(oldcat) == 0){
    $(this).attr('data-init',newcat); 
     $(this).html(newcat);
  }
  });

var area = document.getElementsByClassName(oldcat)[0];
$(area).find("p:first").html(newcat);

$(area).removeClass(oldcat).addClass(newcat);

alert("Category updated");

}
else{
  alert(arr[1]);
}
$(save_button).html('Save');
$(save_button).attr("disabled",false);


    }
else{
$(save_button).html('Save');
$(save_button).attr("disabled",false);
}

  }


  xmlhttp.open("GET","url.php?oldmain="+encodeURIComponent(oldmain)+"&oldcat="+encodeURIComponent(oldcat)+"&newmain="+encodeURIComponent(newmain)+"&newcat="+encodeURIComponent(newcat),true);

  xmlhttp.send();



}
```

Edit code is written above please check it is written above , i am not able to find error , that is what i am doing , Rest everywhere this type of approach is working , i am not understand it

Comment: Who is `save_button`? Should't be places under quotes like  `$('save_button') `?

Comment: @MaraBlack It's the button in the HTML, the value is passed within the arguments of the inline listener. There doesn't seem to be a `save_button` tag in the markup, hence your suggestion won't work.

Comment: I can provide complete function if required

Comment: Ah, my bad, didn't saw..

Comment: @aryanagarwal Can you please elaborate "_The lines inside savecategory does'nt work_" What does that mean, the button doesn't get disabled? The span doesn't occur into the button? Something else?

Comment: @Teemu yes button dont disable and no span inside button , rest  every line of function works

Comment: Better if  you create an executable code snippet of the issues.

Comment: I can't [reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/wdu8nr5e/) the issue, the code seems to work as it is ..? Notice, that the span element is empty, there's nothing to see in that inline element.

Comment: @Teemu it should add a bootstrap loader inside button

Comment: OK. Is this table inside of a form element? If it is, everything works as expected, but then the page is possibly refreshed, as a button element without the type attribute inside a form submits the form by default.

Comment: @Teemu it is not a form , it is a table only

Comment: Ah ... Here: `columns[2].innerHTML = ...` (in the onreadystatechange success handler) you're resetting the content of the cell without the disabled attribute and the span in the new button.

Comment: @Teemu yes that is what I want when successful remove the spinner

Comment: The ajax responses so fast you hardly have time to detect the spinner.

Comment: @Teemu , no when i turn my wifi off it should show endless spinner

Comment: @Teemu so what should i do

Comment: @Teemu please post this as a answer , thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've edited the question, we can see, that the Save button is restored in the `else` block in the `readystatechange` handler when it detects the response wasn't successful. However, `readystatechange` fires multiple times, and you're overriding the content of the original Save button each time the event fires, and not setting the spinner-span, and setting its `disabled` attribute to `false`, until the request actually detects a succesful response.

To fix this, listen `load` event on the XHR object instead of `readystatechange`, it fires only once. Check the status of the request, and if not successful (200), the `else` block will restore the Save button. You don't need to reset the button in the success handler, as the button will be removed from the DOM when you're setting `innerHTML` of the cell. A shortened code for this:

```
function savecategory(but, save_button) {
  var row = but.parentNode,
    columns = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
  // Show the loadtime Save button
  $(save_button).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span> Save');
  $(save_button).attr("disabled", true);

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      columns[2].innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editcategory(this.parentNode)"><i class="zmdi zmdi-edit zmdi-hc-lg"></i></button>';      
    } else {
      // Unsuccessful AJAX call, restore the Save button
      $(save_button).html('Save');
      $(save_button).attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
  // 
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "...", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating it in the static HTML then just use .ready(handler) or .on("load", handler).

f you're using jQuery's load() function then there's a callback you can run when the contents been loaded:

**$('#element').load('sompage.html', function(){ /* callback */ });**

In the callback function you can write you function to call the funtion.I hope this works for you.Thanks

Comment: what do you mean can you give me sample related to my case